# How to relate x + y-axis of a barchart to a given dataframes columns on plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have a small dataframe and want to derive a barchart from it. The barchart will have 2 y-axis inputs fpr each x-axis value. I used the plotly documentation to proceed as far as possible, but somehow I can't relate the columns to the inputs.

This is my dataframe:

```
    Club            FTHG    FTAG
0   Augsburg        24      19
1   Bayern Munich   56      36
2   Dortmund        40      24
3   Ein Frankfurt   26      19
4   FC Koln         20      15
```

And the code:

```
data = [go.Bar(
                x=Club.index, y=FTHG.values, name = 'Goals'
        )]

layout = go.Layout(title = 'Goals')


trace0 = go.Bar(
    x=[Club.index],
    y=[FTHG.index],
    name='Home Goals',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgb(49,130,189)'
    )
)
trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=[Club.index],
    y=[FTAG.index],
    name='Away Goals',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgb(204,204,204)',
    )
)

data = [trace0, trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(tickangle=-45),
    barmode='group',
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='angled-text-bar')
```

And the error:

```
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-38-2dcf55a0f165> in <module>
>       1 data = [go.Bar(
> ----> 2                 x=Club.index, y=FTHG.values, name = 'Goals'
>       3         )]
>       4 
>       5 layout = go.Layout(title = 'Goals')
> 
> NameError: name 'Club' is not defined
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `x` and `y`. If you have pandas DataFrame and want to assign the column - use `df["Club"]` or `df.Club`. You can assign `df.index` - in that case he will be a list such that [0,1,2,3,4].

Code:

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Club": ["Augsburg", "Bayern Munich", "Dortmund",
                            "Ein Frankfurt", "FC Koln"],
                   "FTHG": [24, 56, 40, 26, 20],
                   "FTAG": [19, 36, 24, 19, 15]})

trace0 = go.Bar(
    x=df["Club"],
    y=df["FTHG"],
    name='Home Goals',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgb(49,130,189)'
    )
)
trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=df["Club"],
    y=df["FTAG"],
    name='Away Goals',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgb(204,204,204)',
    )
)

data = [trace0, trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(tickangle=-45),
    barmode='group',
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig, filename='angled-text-bar')
```

And you will get a nice plot:

[image: Stacked Bar Chart]